# How to correctly use source at JQuery Autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Background: Beginner, trying to create my first solo project, working with PyCharm.

Problem\Question: unable to correctly implement the Autocomplete widget for JQuery. I have a list in my Python code that I want to use in my HTML GUI but I can't seem to be able to send\use it in my HTML script.

I'm trying to either:

1. Send the list to the HTML side using Flask's render_template and re-rendering (hope i'm using the correct term) it there, which I gather is bad practice but I wanted to try anyway.
2. Providing a URL to the localhost in the source part.

Python code:

```
from threading import Timer
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# code to get the data from, the website I'm scraping goes here, kupot being the data
str_kupot = []
for child in kupot.children:
    str_kupot.extend(child)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/listkupot')
def listkupot():
    return render_template("test2.html", new_kupot=str_kupot)

@app.route('/display')
def display():
    return render_template('Autocomplete.html')

def open_browser():
    webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:2000/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Timer(1, open_browser).start();
    app.run(debug=False, port=2000)
```

test2:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for item in new_kupot %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Autocomplete (taken from: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  $.get(http://127.0.0.1/test2)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm completely misunderstanding how to correctly define the URL for the source, but I've also tried using the autocomplete code in the "test2" after re-rendering the list and using source = new_kupot but stil getting a 404 error...
been stuck on this for quite a while, really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction

Comment: did you try with `$.get('http://127.0.0.1/test2')` single quotes? If yes then can you please share the error in console.

Comment: Yes, fixed the naming convention and tested.
When accessing 127.0.0.1:2000 I can see the printed list, but when accessing "127.0.0.1:2000/Display" I'm getting 
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."